# ConstraintLayout (appears to) uses HUGE amounts of memory (up to 1GB) on RecyclerView depending on the amount of items in the list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, out-of-memory

My app throws OutOfMemoryError when loading a large list with 6090 items in the RecyclerView.
I have a RecyclerView inside a fullscreen DialogFragment which I use as a FileExplorer, and particularly huge folders will take longer to open (which is to be expected), but opening these BEHEMOTHS of folders will crash the app. 
It's an images folder, but I don't load any images, I merely use a classic png drawable as icon depending on the file type.

Okay, with that out of the way, by using the profiler tool, at one point there was a 1.0GB spike on memory usage:

[image: 1GB memory usage spike]

And the AppHeap section is dominated by ConstraintLayout related stuff:

[image: AppHeap]

And the first[F class has a lot of onMeasure calls and the like:
[image]

The OutOfMemoryError message on the run tab was:

```
at java.lang.Throwable.nativeFillInStackTrace(Native method)
        at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Throwable.java:775)
        at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:258)
        at java.lang.Error.<init>(Error.java:70)
        at java.lang.VirtualMachineError.<init>(VirtualMachineError.java:53)
        at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>(OutOfMemoryError.java:58)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:829)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:531)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:461)
        at goldengentleman.goldennotebook.adapters.FileExplorerAdapter$FilesViewHolder$Companion.from(FileExplorerAdapter.kt:153)
        at goldengentleman.goldennotebook.adapters.FileExplorerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FileExplorerAdapter.kt:52)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7201)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6332)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6216)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6212)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2314)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4215)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3615)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24967)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:736)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:399)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:105)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:232)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:113)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1480)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1555)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7134)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7134)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24967)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7134)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:992)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24967)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3270)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2300)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1861)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8478)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

And it pointed to this block of code (I show "from"s definition on the below ViewHolder code snippet):

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent : ViewGroup, viewType : Int) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder = when (viewType) {
        MODE_FOLDERS -> FoldersViewHolder.from(parent)
        MODE_FILES -> FilesViewHolder.from(parent)
        else -> FilesViewHolder.from(parent)
    }
```

Okay, now to the layout file and then ViewHolder code:

row_file_explorer_file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id = "@+id/root"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "75dp"
    android:background = "@drawable/border_square"
    android:foreground = "@drawable/custom_ripple_no_border">

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/file_name_textView"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart = "16dp"
        android:ellipsize = "start"
        android:singleLine = "true"
        android:textColor = "?attr/primary_text_color"
        android:textSize = "20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "@+id/file_icon_imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf = "@+id/file_icon_imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "@+id/file_icon_imageView"
        tools:text = "File file file" />

    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/file_icon_imageView"
        android:layout_width = "50dp"
        android:layout_height = "50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart = "16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop = "16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "16dp"
        android:tint = "?attr/primary_text_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent"
        app:srcCompat = "@drawable/folder_icon"
        tools:ignore = "ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/file_format_textView"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd = "8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "8dp"
        android:textColor = "?attr/secondary_text_color"
        android:textSize = "12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
        tools:text = "Image File" />

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/file_size_textView"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop = "8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd = "8dp"
        android:textColor = "?attr/secondary_text_color"
        android:textSize = "12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent"
        tools:text = "100KB" />

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/time_created_textView"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop = "4dp"
        android:textColor = "?attr/secondary_text_color"
        android:textSize = "12sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "@+id/file_name_textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf = "@+id/file_name_textView"
        tools:text = "25/08/2000" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the ViewHolder:

```
class FilesViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    private val fileName : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_name_textView)
    private val fileIcon : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_icon_imageView)
    private val fileFormat : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_format_textView)
    private val fileSize : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_size_textView)
    private val fileTimeCreated : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_created_textView)
    private val root : ConstraintLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.root)

    fun bind(item : FileModel, context : Context, adapter : FileExplorerAdapter) {

        if (item.fileType == FileType.FOLDER) {
            fileName.text = item.name
            fileIcon.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.folder_icon))
            fileSize.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            fileTimeCreated.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            fileFormat.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_square)
        } else {
            fileSize.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            fileTimeCreated.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            fileFormat.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            fileName.text = item.name
            fileFormat.text = item.extension
            fileSize.text = item.sizeInMB
            fileTimeCreated.text = Time.convertUnixToDateTime(item.timeCreated)
            val ext = item.extension
            fileIcon.apply {
                setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(
                    if (item.fileType == FileType.FOLDER) R.drawable.folder_icon
                    else if (ext == "pdf") R.drawable.pdf_box
                    else if (ext == "doc" || ext == "docx") R.drawable.file_word
                    else if (ext == "mp3" || ext == "3gp") R.drawable.music
                    else if (ext == "mp4" || ext == "webm") R.drawable.video
                    else if (ext == "jpg" || ext == "png") R.drawable.image
                    else R.drawable.file))
            }
            if (item in adapter.selectedFiles) {
                root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_square_selected)
            } else {
                root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_square)
            }
        }

        root.setOnClickListener {
            if (item.fileType == FileType.FILE) {
                if (!adapter.inMultiSelectionMode) {
                    adapter.fileSelectedListener?.returnFiles(adapter.selectedFiles.apply { add(item) })
                } else {
                    if (item !in adapter.selectedFiles) {
                        adapter.selectedFiles.add(item)
                        root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_square_selected)
                    } else {
                        adapter.selectedFiles.remove(item)
                        root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_square)
                        if (adapter.selectedFiles.isEmpty()) adapter.inMultiSelectionMode = false
                    }
                }
            } else if (item.fileType == FileType.FOLDER) {
                if (adapter.selectedFiles.isEmpty()) {
                    adapter.folderSelectedCallback?.openTheFolder(item)
                }
            }
            adapter.fileSelectedListener?.returnFiles(adapter.selectedFiles)
        }

        root.setOnLongClickListener {
            if (item.fileType == FileType.FILE) {
                if (!adapter.inMultiSelectionMode && adapter.selectedFiles.isEmpty()) {
                    adapter.inMultiSelectionMode = true
                }
                if (item !in adapter.selectedFiles) {
                    adapter.selectedFiles.add(item)
                    root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_square_selected)
                } else {
                    adapter.selectedFiles.remove(item)
                    root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_square)
                    if (adapter.selectedFiles.isEmpty()) {
                        adapter.inMultiSelectionMode = false
                    }
                }
                adapter.fileSelectedListener?.returnFiles(adapter.selectedFiles)
            }
            true
        }

    }

    companion object {
        fun from(parent : ViewGroup) : FilesViewHolder = FilesViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_file_explorer_file, parent, false))
    }
}
```

```
I think this is all. The way this Adapter is coded is similar (read equal) to Udacity/Google's Android RecyclerView with Kotlin tutorial on Udacity.
My guess is that RecyclerView is creating ***way*** more ViewHolders than will be used, and something I could have done wrong with the ConstraintLayour is being magnified by this abnormal behavior of RecyclerView, but other than that, nothing on Google got me closer to the answer
```

Comment: Can you attach the layout file where recyclerview is declared?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: @Mike M. sorry, i didn't know about that! thought my previous question was lost in the limbo